# Reducing amount of http requests by grouping queries

Tags: angularjs, http, database-design

So I have a bunch of chatty http requests in my Angular 1 app which are bottle necking many of the other requests.
Imagine I have a list of Users from a **totally different data source** and I make calls to 5 different tables such as:

```
user.signup
+-----+------------+
| uid |    date    |
+-----+------------+
|   1 | 2016-12-13 |
|   2 | 2016-12-01 |
+-----+------------+
user.favourite_color
+-----+-------+
| uid | color |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | red   |
|   5 | blue  |
|   7 | green |
+-----+-------+
user.location
+-----+-----------+
| uid | location  |
+-----+-----------+
|   2 | uk        |
|   3 | france    |
|   9 | greenland |
+-----+-----------+
```

The reason they are in different tables are because the fields are **optional**.
The way I see it I have 3 options:

### Put them in 1 table

So I could just group them all in 1 table and have a bunch of null columns but that just doesn't sit right with me in terms of DB design.

```
+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
| uid |    date    | location  | color |
+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
|   1 | 2016-12-13 | null      | red   |
|   2 | 2016-12-01 | uk        | null  |
|   3 | null       | greenland | null  |
|   5 | null       | null      | blue  |
+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
```

### Join them all with 1 request

So I could just have one query that joins all these tables but the way I see it they would have to be full joins with the expectation that some uid's wouldn't exist in some tables. e.g.

```
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
| uid  |    date    | l_uid | location  | c_uid | color |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1    | 2016-12-13 | null  | null      | 1     | red   |
| 2    | 2016-12-01 | 2     | uk        | null  | null  |
| null | null       | 3     | greenland | null  | null  |
| null | nul        | null  | null      | 5     | blue  |
+------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

which is probably even worse!

### Change the way the requests are made?

Maybe make some clever changes how the requests are made:

```
function activate() {
    $q.all([requestSignupDate(), requestFaveColor(), requestLocation(), ....])
    .then(function (data) {
        //do a bunch of stuff with the data
    });
}
```

which I want to change to:

```
function activate() {
    requestUserData();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical ORM problem - precisely this database does not provide a better way of storing the `user` as an `entity`.

The entity properties are spread out in multiple tables and due to being optional you are taxed to do left joins with multiple tables.

So you have to essentially solve that problem first. You have several options or (non-options without knowing requirements.)

> **Put them in one table**

If you can use nullable columns and refactor your application - this is preferable. I see that your other tables have just one or two more fields. Heavily normalized tables saves some space and with no data repetition other normalization benefits are moot.

> **Join them all with 1 request**

Only if your query stays performant. Can you use `left join` ? 
You would do this if the above option is difficult. Use this only as a quick fix.

**Other options To solve Database Problem**

1. Use server side caching if feasible.
2. If feasible use a different NoSQL database (e.g. MongoDB)

> **Change the way the requests are made?**

Do you really need all the properties upfront ? The web is asynchronous so why not keep things async. Use `$q.all` only if you need all the properties. For example the user may not even navigate/scroll to certain part of the page to see stuff so why may queries in the first place.

Along with this you can cluster your server side and the database so that these queries fall on multiple machines and load gets distributed. You may get some items retrieved in parallel.

If the number of columns are all that you have and the tables are all that you mentioned i.e. the supplemental tables have fewer properties I would go with **Put them in 1 table** option.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've only ever worked with Relational data from 1 source and having this problem was new to me, I just needed a new way of thinking about it, I decided to change it to 1 table early on before the app gets too big and Joins are just going to be pretty difficult.

Comment: Note: I discovered most of the bottleneck was caused by the return promises. Now I know this might be obvious because I've explicitly told it to wait, HOWEVER after doing some testing I discovered it was taking an unusually long amount of time to return. (perhaps I understood or implemented it incorrectly) anyway its super fast now!

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't using nullable fields sit right with you? `NULL` exists because it's useful, and a profile table with optional values for a fixed set of fields is practically the textbook case for invoking it. If fields can be dynamically redefined (eg swapping out "favorite color" for "favorite food"), it's another story, but that's not a requirement in what you've described.

Comment: You're right, its just when I've always designed relational databases you want to avoid a bunch of unnecessary nullable columns when you can just have a fact table joining all the optional dimension tables together, but that's just because normally you would be storing the unifying ID in the same place as the information but in this case it's different. Thanks!